# Is it possible to set 2 different cursors for a Checkbutton widget (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse-cursor

I have searched on the internent but without response. I use a tkinter Checkbutton with the indicatoron=FALSE, which makes it seems like it is just a button.

I have set a cursor, but I wanted to know if it is possible to set 2 different cursors for the on/off status of the checkbutton.

For example:

```
test = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text=self.name, indicatoron=False, selectcolor="green", background="red", variable=self.varbutton, command=self.launchsound, cursor="plus") 
test.pack()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it depends on your variable `varbutton` in your `command`:

```
import tkinter as tk

def changeCursor():
    if varbutton.get():
        test['cursor'] = 'hand2'
    else:
        test['cursor'] = 'plus'
    # pass

r = tk.Tk()
varbutton = tk.BooleanVar()
test = tk.Checkbutton(r, text="a", indicatoron=False, selectcolor="green", background="red", cursor="plus", command=changeCursor, variable=varbutton)
test.pack()
r.mainloop()
```